# How to display a image in floating frame via PHP imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

I tried to show the image with -raise and frame command with PHP and imagemagick but not succeed the output i want.

I want same output as [this link](http://static.greatbigcanvas.com/images/singlecanvas_floatingframe_floatblack/panoramic-images/brooklyn-bridge-new-york-ny-usa,63829.jpg?max=540).

```
$photo=$_GET['url'];
$cmd = " convert $photo -mattecolor $color -frame 22x22+10+3 -matte -virtual-pixel transparent   -distort Perspective \"0,0 0,3  225,20 225,20   213,160 213,145   0,100 0,100 \"  "."   abc.png";
exec($cmd);
```

Comment: As a beside, your code is highly vulnerable as it is. I highly recommend using `escapeshellcmd()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php)

Comment: Thanks Joel for your recommendation.i will use the functions now.

Comment: And where is the photo you are using please?

Comment: Mark , the path of image is dynamically passed to script. In $photo variable there is the path of image.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the numbers in your command relate to the geometry of a specific image and I wanted to see that specific image.

Comment: Basicly i am working on a site where images are products and shown in floating frame at runtime.So there is not some specific image.  the link of example is      http://canvas.sunilkumar.us/product-sunset-over-the-sea-point.html